# bootstrap - stack horizontal menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created menu with collapsable class `.nav-collapse` in bootstrap. When I resize window it disappears. So I've overrided `.nav-collapse` class with this css:

```
.nav-collapse, .nav-collapse.collapse {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

This is not the desired way of doing it everytime. Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHjZN/) and remove above style from css. It will be easier to understand.

**QUESTION:** Is there a simple built in solution for stacking horizontal menu in bootstrap?

Comment: It would be better if you complemented your question with a sample code on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Dhiraj Bodicherla edited my question and added jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap does have built in stacking : http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs

This would be the correct layout for `.nav-collapse` in your situation:

```
<div class="top-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then what I would do is override the default media query from `bootstrap-responsive.css` in a separate `bootstrap-overrides.css`:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .top-nav .nav-collapse, .top-nav .nav-collapse.collapse {
        height: auto;
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcd018/Y5YjV/14/)

Comment: The point is I don't want to have icon and basicly I would like to find something similar to what I have now.

Comment: Well in that case, you can just override the default media query that hides the menu, see my edits and also this : http://jsfiddle.net/dcd018/Y5YjV/14/

Comment: That's what I've already did in my original jsfiddle example. I would like to avoid overriding bootstrap core

Comment: Your not actually overriding the core css if you add the parent class `.top-nav`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "nav" class, during resize it will be turned into buttons. Your request can be achieved by using "nav-stacked" class.Look at this example http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs -> Stackable

Comment: Can you make an example to get my desired result with `stackable`?